Dielectric constant and Refractive index with drasticly different behavior for biological tissues
Here's the context, similar to my last question but a bit different. I'm studying stacked biological tissues assumed to behave like dielectrics. Using the modified cole-cole equation:
$$\tilde{\varepsilon}_r (\omega )= \varepsilon_\infty + \sum\limits_n \frac{\Delta \varepsilon_n}{1 +(i \omega \tau_n)^{(1-\alpha_n)}} + \frac{\sigma_m }{i \omega \varepsilon_0 }$$
with $\varepsilon_\infty$ the one when $\omega \tau >>1$, $\varepsilon_s$ when $\omega \tau <<1$ and $\Delta \varepsilon_n$ the difference of the two previous. $\tau$ is the relaxation time (like the one in Debyes equation). $\sigma_m/(i \omega \varepsilon_0)$ is the ionic contribution with the ionic conductivity, we can calculate $\varepsilon_r '$ and $\varepsilon_r''$. Here are the graph of the dielecetric constant (real-blue circle left axis- and imaginary- red triangle, right axis- parts) for the four different tissues (the grey vertical lines indicates where the imaginary part crosses the real part):

Please ignore the top x axis for now, it is a work in progress-
Then, since it is known that the tissues I'm studying are lossy, I've derived the following equations:
$$n' = \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}\left(\sqrt{\varepsilon_r'^2 + \varepsilon_r"^2} +\varepsilon_r' \right)} \\
n'' = \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}\left(\sqrt{\varepsilon_r'^2 + \varepsilon_r"^2} -\varepsilon_r' \right)} $$
And when compared to measured data, each equation has a critical empirical exponent to fit experimental datas, leading to refractive index (real-blue circle left axis- and imaginary- red triangle, right axis- parts) such as (same letters are the same tissues- the grey vertical line indicates where the imaginary part crosses the real part):

Please ignore the top x axis for now, it is a work in progress-
What I'm having a hard time to explain is why are the imaginary (1E4 to 1E9) parts that much stronger than the real part (1E2 ish) at lower frequencies? Or if it is possible at all?
I know the tissues behave like conductors/metals below a certain frequency, killing any propagating applied electric field in the bulk, which is a part of the explanation, but not the whole picture. Over this, there's the anisotropic behavior, for optical and electromagnetic stimuli, of one of the layers that complexify things. We do observe all of these phenomenon with transmission calculation using boundaries condition (sin, cos, sinh and cosh naturally appear in the equations. They're using k, $\kappa$, n and n' in them --real and imaginary parts of wave vector and refractive index respectively-- in addition to tissue thickness).
Medical literature discuss little of low frequency spectrum as this domain is mostly interested in the visible (and near) spectrum of light, with little to no physics in them. For its part, physics literature is focused mostly on non biological/living medium/tissue.
Any ideas, suggestion or comments are welcome. Cheers and thank you

You don't need much static conductivity $\sigma_m$ to make the imaginary part of the relative permittivity very large at low frequencies, due to the $1/\omega$-dependence. Any model satisfying Maxwell's equations shows this (including yours).
Is this what you mean or are you saying that the static conductivity should be extremely small? With many types of biological tissue, you get static conductivity due to free ion movement (i.e. dissolved salts).

Welcome to Physics.SE. Note that answers in general shouldn't include requests for clarification... when you reach reputation 50 you can comment on a question to do that.

Hi, yes the static ionic conductivity of tissues is quite small, and I was surprised by the results at first. But indeed, free ion movement, such as those of salt, it would justify the low results.
I'm reviewing litterature to see if a rise in the salt concentration (due to membra permeability of Ca2+ and K+) could rise conductivity as well! Thank you for the interesting answer
